# Remove-TeamUser command from Powershell module for teams throwing an error

Tags: microsoft-teams

The following command throws an error while removing an owner from microsoft teams.

### Remove-TeamUser  -GroupId 7ad89f19-1c20-4f51-a520-1228002ac93d -User Megan.ryn.admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com

ERROR:

Remove-TeamUser : Error occurred while executing Remove-TeamUser
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource '7ad89f19-1c20-4f51-a520-1228002ac93d' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property
objects are not present.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 7676f32b-2ed3-49fc-8013-69ea4a63b97b
  DateTimeStamp: 2018-08-20T11:29:26
HttpStatusCode: Request_ResourceNotFound
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-TeamUser  -GroupId 7ad89f19-1c20-4f51-a520-1228002ac93d -User  ...

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-TeamUser], ApiException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.ErrorHandling.ApiException,Microsoft.TeamsCmdle ts.PowerShell.Custom.RemoveTeamUser
```

Strangely its the Teams GUID which the command reports as not being able to find. I can confirm further operations on adding new users to this team via powershell work fine

Some background

The team was provisioned via C# using Graph api.  The user in question is the admin account under which the C# application was running.

I can confirm that the user Meganryn.admin has sufficient permissions

thanks
a

Comment: Remove-TeamUser : Error occurred while executing Remove-TeamUser
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource '7ad89f19-1c20-4f51-a520-1228002ac93d' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property
objects are not present.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 7676f32b-2ed3-49fc-8013-69ea4a63b97b
  DateTimeStamp: 2018-08-20T11:29:26

Comment: Which version of Teams Powershell module are you using? Could you please try once 
with [v0.9.3](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/0.9.3) and share the request/resposne for failed request?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `user ID` not the `user try`...

```
$megryn = get-teamuser -groupid 7ad89f19-1c20-4f51-a520-1228002ac93d | where-object{$_.Name -like "Megan.ryn.admin} | select -expandproperty userid

remove-teamuser -groupid 7ad89f19-1c20-4f51-a520-1228002ac93d -user $megryn
```